# OAuth 2.0 JSON doesn't contain client secret,

Tags: oauth

I am trying to write data with Google Sheets API. To achive that, I need to use Access Token in my request. Every single tutorial says that I need to put client secret and client ID in some kind of software (for example Postman Authentication) and that will give me Access Token ready for request. The problem is "client secret" is missing on my Google Cloud Console Credentials page. I have seen something about generating secret on my machine, but i have no idea how to do it. Can anybody please help me?